# How to Close Parent Popup from Iframe containing aspx page button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I have one popup which contain iframe and inside iframe i called `.aspx` page . So how I can close parent popup from `.aspx` close button . I'm not using `AjaxModalPopup`.

I tried `$('#formModal', window.parent.document).hide();` it just hide the popup but does not allow to click on the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the .aspx page in the iframe you can use this:

```
<span onclick="parent.ClosePopup('send optional variable')">Close this popup</span>
```

And on the page with the iframe just a normal javascript function.

```
function ClosePopup(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    //code to close the popup
}
```

> This only works with pages on the same domain, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

I am using magnificPopup and it also using iframe. Below is my code,

```
 if (typeof parent.$.magnificPopup != 'undefined') {
            parent.$.magnificPopup.close();
        }
```